# Lower bound for $2+ \cos(t)$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I was doing this question on convergence of improper integrals where in our book they have used the fact that $2+ \cos(t) \ge1$. Can somebody prove this?

Comment: The minimum value for $\cos t$ is $-1$, so $2+\cos t$ has minimum of $1$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos (t) \ge -1$, we have $2 + \cos (t) \ge 2 - 1 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

More formally:

$$\begin{array}{r c l}
-1 \le &  \cos t &\le  1,\quad \forall t\\
2 - 1 \le & 2+\cos t &\le  2+ 1\\
1 \le&  2+\cos t &\le  3  
\end{array}
$$